# Which of the following code have lesser time complexity? Please explain how to calculate it

Tags: arrays, time-complexity, subset, space-complexity, tradeoff

Following is the code to calculate subsets of a given array:

1. ***Bit Manipulation Method:*** How to  analyse it?

   ```
    vector<vector<int>> subsets(vector<int>& nums)
     {
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());

        int num_subset = pow(2, nums.size()); 
        vector<vector<int> > res(num_subset, vector<int>());

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < num_subset; j++)
                if ((j >> i) & 1)
                    res[j].push_back(nums[i]);

        return res;  
     }
   ```
2. ***Backtracking Method:*** How to analyse it

   ```
        vector<vector<int>> subsets(vector<int>& nums)
         {
           sort(nums.begin(), nums.end()); // sort the original array
           vector<vector<int>> subs;
           vector<int> sub;  
           genSubsets(nums, 0, sub, subs);
           return subs; 
         }

       void genSubsets(vector<int>& nums, int start, vector<int>& sub,vector<vector<int>>& subs)
         {
           subs.push_back(sub);
           for (int i = start; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            sub.push_back(nums[i]);
            genSubsets(nums, i + 1, sub, subs);
            sub.pop_back();
          }
        }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Vector operations:
- `push_back` and `pop_back` are both `O(1)`
- Constructor with size argument `n` is `O(n)`

---

*Bit manipulation method:*

- `sort` is `O(n log n)`
- Construction of `res` is `O(nums_subset) = O(2^n)`
- Outer loop is executed `n` times, inner by `nums_subset = 2^n` times.

  [image]

---

*Backtracking method:*

- Again, `sort` is `O(n log n)`
- Each `genSubsets` call loops through `nums.size() - start` times, each time performing a recursive call with 1 less loop.

  [image: enter code here]

---

Which is bigger? By Stirling's approximation,

[image]

So *Backtracking* is more costly.